# grails service dead-locking with mysql

Tags: mysql, grails, service, locking, acl

I'm trying to add a long list of file into mysql and use spring ACL service with grails to attach permission.
So, in my controller i have:

```
Files.withTransaction {
            Files file = new Files(dataStore:ds,created:new Date(),path:target,name:fileName,contentType:contentType,contentLength:contentLength,isFolder:false).save(flush:true)
            file = Files.lock(file.id)
            filesService.addPermission(file, username ,BasePermission.ADMINISTRATION)
        }
```

the i have no worries with the Files domain object, it supports huge amount of data ,(specially since i 've disabled versioning in mysql), the problem is on filesService which uses aclUtilService,

```
@Transactional
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_GROUP_OWNER')")
    def addPermission(Files f, String username,Permission permission) {
        aclUtilService.addPermission f,username,permission
    }
```

Randomly i have the following deadlock (optmistic?)error :

> Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction.
>   Stacktrace follows:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException:
>   Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1045)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2280)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2265)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.acl.AclService.save(AclService.groovy:330)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.acl.AclService.createEntries(AclService.groovy:198)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.acl.AclService.updateAcl(AclService.groovy:176)
>     at
>   GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin$_closure5_closure18_closure19.doCall(GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin.groovy:170)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.acl.AclUtilService.addPermission(AclUtilService.groovy:90)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.acl.AclUtilService.addPermission(AclUtilService.groovy:67)
>     at
>   GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin$_closure5_closure18_closure19.doCall(GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin.groovy:170)
>     at
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxx.FilesService.addPermission(FilesService.groovy:34)
>     at
>   GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin$_closure5_closure18_closure19.doCall(GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin.groovy:170)
>     at
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxQuantumController$_uploadToS3_closure1$$ENzPdDAW.doCall(QuantumController.groovy:87)
>     at
>   org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:686)
>     at
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxx.QuantumController$$ENzPdDAW.uploadToS3(QuantumController.groovy:84)
>     at
>   grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
>     at
>   grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
>     at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:149)   at
>   net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:259)
>     at
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:202)
>     at
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:175)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just encapsulated the transaction in controller and use @Transactional in the service to solve the issue:

```
Files.withTransaction {
                    Files file = new Files(
...
                    if (file.validate()) {
                        file.save()
                        filesService.addPermission(file,username,BasePermission.ADMINISTRATION)

...}
}
```